# 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split

I've got this code to retrieve the name of an investment fund starting from the input ISIN code:

```
isin = raw_input("isin of the fund? ")  
name = c.execute("select name from funds where isin like ?", ('%'+isin+'%',))  
s = c.fetchall()
```

Now I need to process the name splitting it and removing certain words:

```
stop_words=['Cap','Ptf', '(EUR)', 'EUR', 'USD', '(D)', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'E' ]

final_list=[]
for i in s[0].split():
    if i not in stop_words:
        final_list.append(i)

print(" ".join(final_list))
```

and what I got as error is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I'm a newbie and understand the problem, I just don't understand how to convert my list in a string to split it. Thank you for your help.

Edit: grammar

Comment: Are you sure `s[0]` is what you think it is?

Comment: try to `print(s[0])` and `print(type(s[0]))` before the for loop to check what you're doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `cursor.fetchall()` is a *list of lists*, so you'd need to index into it twice, e.g.:

```
rows = c.fetchall()
if rows:
    name = rows[0][0]
    ...
```

However, since [ISIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number) codes are supposed to be unique, you could probably use `cursor.fetchone()` to fetch just a single row and also get rid of `LIKE`:

```
c.execute("select name from funds where isin = ?", (isin,))
row = c.fetchone()
if row:
    name = row[0]
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that I needed to index into it twice.